# MySQL query to return a fraction of the rows in the table each day

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to write a query that will give me a fraction of all the rows in a table but a different fraction each day. Lets say I will run this query once a day each week. I want 1/7 of the rows in the table. Suppose I had a table with one column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `active_databases` (
`database_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`database_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Put some sample data into it:

```
INSERT INTO `active_databases` (`database_name`) VALUES ('db1'),('db2'),('db3'),('db4'),('db5'),('db6'),('db7'),('db8'),('db9'),('db10');
```

If I run my query on Monday I would want it to give me the first 1/7 of those rows rounded up. Then again on Tuesday give me the next 1/7 of the rows but not the ones from Monday. Then Wednesday give me the next 1/7 of the rows but not the ones from Monday/Tuesday and so on. The following week the query will start over again and return the first 1/7 of the rows and continue.

How could this query be written?

Comment: Pretty sure you won't be able to do this with a single query. Why not just run a COUNT(*) and then LIMIT as necessary in a subsequent query?

Comment: Someone might cleverly script a stored procedure for this task passing a dynamic parameter. But this is a looped object-oriented programming question that then calls a parameterized query in MySQL each day. Consider a solution in C#, Java, PHP, Python, R, or whatever your flavor.

Comment: "If I run my query on Monday". Can you guarantee that the query will be run once a day? If not, do you still want it to reset the following week or only when all records have been selected?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. Yes, this is more complicated than I realized for a query. I'll have to script it as stored procedure or scripting language and get a count and use the LIMIT as necessary. @Parfait - I was thinking to schedule the query with a scheduler so that it only runs once per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think one query will be enough here.
What you could do is add a field to the schema. The value of this field will be 0 if the record hasn't been used yet, and 1 if it has.

Then figure out the number of records in the schema with `count(*)`, we'll store that value in `total_records`.

What you can do is select all records where this flag is set to 0, but select no more than 1/7 of the total size.

If `len_div_7` holds `total_records/7`, you can use this query to accomplish the above:

`select * from mytable where flag=0 limit len_div_7`.

So you got your 1/7 then.

Now, you want to be sure to update the records so you don't select them next time by going through each record and updating the `flag` to 1.

If at some point, you select less than 1/7 (e.g. none of them if total records is divisible by 7), that means that you need to cycle back around again, so reset the flag to 0 for all records.

*Note:* the solution changes if the number of records in the table changes throughout the week. This is assuming the size is fixed.